# undefined local variable or method `end_form_tag'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code on _search_boxes.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <%= end_form_tag %>
```

but the last line shows  that undefined local variable or method `end_form_tag' error

Comment: I updated my answer.have a look at it.

Comment: anybody know how to do this in nodejs, I'm getting same error in NodeJS

Answer (score 2):

`<%end_form_tag %>` works with Rails versions prior 3 and now it is deprecated.Instead use `<%end%>` or even just using `</form>` will also works.

So your should looks like this

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) %>
<%= text_field_tag :q %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

**Update**

you are missing a `do` in your `form_tag` and remove `=` in `<%= end %>`.It should be like this

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
    <% end %>
```

For more details,see this [API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_tag('/search', method: :get) do -%>
  <%= text_field_tag 'q' %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Save' %>
<% end -%>
```

for more information refer [ruby-doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<% end %>` instead of `<% end_form_tag %>`.`<% end_form_tag %>` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= end_form_tag %>` is deprecated.

Just use

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) %>
<%= text_field_tag :q %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<%= end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

now ,this is _search_box.html.erb

```
    <%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) %>
    <%= text_field_tag :q %>
    <%= submit_tag "Buscarse" %>
    <%= end %>
```

and this is search.thml.erb

```
   <% render :partial => "search_box" %>
   <% if @boxes %>
   <p>Your search "<%= params[:q] %>" produced
   <%= pluralize @boxes.size, "result" %>:</p>
   <%= render(:partial => "boxes") %>
   <% end %>
```

and this is what i get

```
    syntax error, unexpected keyword_end
    ');@output_buffer.append= ( end );@output_buffer.to_s
```

Comment: Try posting it as a edit in your question,but not as an answer though.I will update my answer to youe problem.

Answer (score 0):

The proper code should look like this:

```
<%= form_tag({:action => "search"}, {:method => "get"}) do %>
<%= text_field_tag :q %>
<%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

You shouldn't need an `=` in the `<%= end %>` the only times you use `=` would be when you have some ruby code to show in the application. Hope this helps!